# javascript regex matching 3 digits and 3 letters

Tags: javascript, regex, match

How to match word in string that contain exactly "3 digits and 3 letters"?

e.g. 100BLA

```
var regex = ?;
var string = "word word 100BLA word";
desiredString = string .match(regex);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`\d` matches a digit

`[a-zA-Z]` matches a letter

`{3}` is the quantifier that matches exactly 3 repetitions

`^` Anchor to match the start of the string

`$` Anchor to match the end of the string

So if you use all this new knowledge, you will come to a regex like this:

```
^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

### Update:

Since the input example has changed after I wrote my answer, here the update:

If your word is part of a larger string, you don't need the anchors `^` and `$` instead you have to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`.

```
\b\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}\b
```

Comment: As mentioned in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275661/javascript-regex-matching-3-digits-and-3-letters/16275885#comment23293885_16275885) too, this would not work as it matches start and end of input and not of word.

Comment: @MariaIoannidou, I know exactly what my expression is matching. When I answered this question the example string was `var string = "100BLA word";` and not `var string = "word word 100BLA word";`

Comment: nope, example string has not been changed. and yes it works if the match is not the last word in string

Comment: @stema I didn't say that you don't know :). Although it is not marked as edited, it may have been edited very quickly. I remember also seeing another input that my initial answer was different too. But even with the initial example that wouldn't work, right?

Comment: but the input has not been changed ;)

Answer (score 5):

**INITIAL (incomplete)**

```
var regex = /[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{3}/;
```

**EDIT 1 (incomplete)**

```
var regex = /[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{3}\b/; // used \b for word boundary
```

**EDIT 2 (correct)**

```
var regex = /\b[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{3}\b/; // used \b at start and end for whole word boundary
```

Comment: Try `var str = "Foobar100BLA";` will also be true.

Comment: @stema You are right. If we want a word match we should use the word boundary match **(\b)** at the end of the regex too. But using ^ and $, as you suggest in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16275847/504368) would match start and end of input, so the example string would not match whereas it should.
I'm editing my answer appropriately.

Comment: You need also a wordboundary on the start of the regex otherwise it returns still true on var `string = "word word Foobar100BLA word";`

Comment: @stema Oh I didn't know it, thanx!

Comment: thank you. I am sorry, I accepted Stemas answer as he posted it first