# javascript Regex pattern validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regex pattern which starts with an `i` and followed with 6 numbers. for example: i123456, i098765.

I have followed this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16275847/1691423), and created this regex: `^\[i]{1}[0-9]{6}$` but in [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) validation web site I got an false for the examples above.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is the backslash doing in the regex?

Comment: I never worked with regex, so I don't really know...

Comment: Get rid of it and it should work fine.

Comment: Why not try `^i[0-9]{6}$`

Comment: Post at is an answer and I will accept it :) THANKS @devnull

Comment: Better delete it.  Typos aren't meant to be questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest regex that would do it is: `/^i\d{6}$/`

Answer (score 3):

Things to note:

1. The caret (^) and dollar sign ($) characters at the beginning and end denote the start and end of the line or string respectively, depending on the multiline (m) flag. If you are looking for matches within a string, this regex will fail because it requires the i123456 pattern to be the whole string (or line).
2. You do not need to make a character set, as denoted by including characters in square brackets, for matching a single character. Just write it plainliy.
3. A literal RegExp begins and ends with forward slashes. Some online tools and validators might not recognize your expression as valid unless you include them.

As @kamilkp responded, `/^i\d{6}$/` would be the shortest expression possible if you are attempting to validate the whole input string against the pattern. If you are trying to pluck substrings that match the pattern from a larger string, the simplest pattern would be `/i\d{6}/` or `/i\d{6}/i` if the case of the leading letter 'i' is irrelevant.