# Checking string for 3 letters then 3 numbers

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to be able to check a string so that the first 3 characters in it are letters and the last 3 are numerical, e.g. a rego like "ABC123" and ensure it isnt something like "123ABC" or "1A2B3C"

Comment: And what's your question? Have you tried anything? Have you read the javadoc of java.lang.Character?

Comment: Im not a Java expert, but I would most likely use a regex pattern to help with this. Go ahead and try this approach. You have no question in the post, so I am assuming you need to use a function that checks a string for this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
string.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}.*[0-9]{3}");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pattern with regex:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

if you have anything in between you can use:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z].*[0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern `^[A-Za-z]{3}.*[0-9]{3}$`

```
String test = "ABC123";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]{3}.*[0-9]{3}$").matcher(test);
if (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.print(matcher.group());
}
```

output:

```
ABC123
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check it like this:

```
    if (!"AB1C23".matches("^([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3})")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid!!");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

- `\d` matches a digit
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches a letter
- `{3}` is the quantifier that matches exactly 3 repetitions
- `()` group maches
- `([a-zA-Z]{3})(\\d{3})`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{3})(\\d{3})").matcher("ABC215");
//      Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{3})(\\d{3})").matcher("1A2B3C"); //Macher not find :)
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //ABC215
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //ABC
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); //215
        }
    }
```

[Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275661/javascript-regex-matching-3-digits-and-3-letters)